# error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments and a recursive issue

Tags: c++

first off, I've uploaded my code to paste bin and the link is below for anyone who is interested. The problem i'm experiencing is just as the title says but its more of a question of how do i pass a local string variable into a global variable object from a function. My solution from many hours of searching online is through pass by reference which is fine but actually applying that to my code is where i choked and racked up a lot of time getting confused. That about sums up my first problem and my second problem relates to the constructors I've created which for some reason are recursive despite the fact i'm not calling any functions within a function. That error is completely throwing me for a loop (no pun intended). Regardless, any help is appreciated and upon request I can attempt to elaborate more of my problem but it really should be straight forward with the code posted.

http://pastebin.com/Mm1K4d2t

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow.com. If you have a question about a compiler error, please include the _complete_ and _unedited_ error message(s) in your question. Also please include the relevant lines of code in your question as well, showing which lines are associated with what errors.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/1aXg3nAj Correct pastebin uploaded, i apologize...

Comment: 'Not a real question', what a joke. The question was quite specific and got two reasonable answers. Maybe we should have a 'Closed because OP put his code on pastebin' catagory.

Answer (score 2):

This is a recursive constructor

```
Date::Date()
{
    Date Date;
    Date.year=0;
    Date.day=0;
    Date.month="";
}
```

Constructors are called when constructing objects. What's the first thing you do in this constructor? Construct an object! Hence the recursion. What you meant to write is

```
Date::Date()
{
    year=0;
    day=0;
    month="";
}
```

You've made some other similar errors, which all seem to be related to a misunderstanding of how member variables work. For instance this

```
    static string Date::getMonth();
```

should be this

```
    string getMonth();
```

and this

```
string Date::getMonth()
{
        Date Date;
        return Date.month;
}
```

should be this

```
string Date::getMonth()
{
        return month;
}
```

Similar changes needed for setMonth.

I'm afraid I don't understand your question about global objects and local ones, but given the misunderstandings you have I'm pretty sure it's bogus. Make the changes above (and to setMonth) and then see where you are. Rereading the appropriate chapter on objects in your C++ book would be a good idea as well.

Comment: Hm, thank you for your time and I apologize for the poor format/coding skills.

Comment: @Mark No need to apologize. We were all beginners once.

Answer (score 0):

When you write e.g.

```
return Date.month;
```

your trying to access the `month` member, not of an *object*, but directly in the *class*. This will not work, as members are *declared* in the class, but exists in the *object*.

And if you want to access a member in the current object, then you don't need to prefix it, just use it:

```
return month;
```

Comment: See, this is what confuses me though. When you return month Date.getMonth when called doesn't return month in main. This is why i continually tried to force Date.month to accept the input I was trying to give it.